# Matlab - Incorrect dimensions for raising a matrix to a power

Tags: matlab, vector, angle, area

Suppose we have `a=60` and `B=60`. I am trying to calculate this area:

[image]

when I try this:

```matlab
W = ((u^2)* cot(B) + (v^2 * cot(a))/8;
```

I get this error:

> Incorrect dimensions for raising a matrix to a power. Check that the matrix is square and the power is a scalar. To perform elementwise matrix powers,
>   use '.^'.

How can I use `u^2` in the right way?

Comment: Are `u` and `v` scalar?

Comment: No they are vectors in 3D. for example v=[5 5 0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `u` and `v` are a vector, you should write `u.^2` and `v.^2` instead (an element-wise operator). When you write `u^2` means `u * u` and it does not mean when `u` is not a squared matrix.

However, if they are vector, it is not meant for computing the value of `W`.

Comment: You mean the formula is for the length of `u` and `v`?

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad yes, indeed.